# What is the regex of any positive number except 0 or 1

Tags: python, regex

It should allow:

```
99
10
100
```

It should not allow:

```
0
1
```

Trying this:

```
r"[^0-1]"
```

but it only take numbers from 2 to 9.

UPDATE:

This is what I was looking for: `([2-9]|\d\d+)`

Comment: More, `[^0-1]` matches `§`, too. Any char other than `1` and `0`. Now, what about `1.25`? Or `45-345`?

Comment: How about 01 and 00?

Comment: @DYZ Should not take these

Comment: @Natasha Edit the question, then (at least the examples).

Comment: Don't check for the shorter string first.

Comment: `([2-9]|\d\d+)` allows 00, 01, 0000, 0001, etc. Are you sure you want it?

Comment: This conversation reminds me of "You have a problem and try a regular expression.  Now you have two problems."

Answer (score 1):

A positive integer number except 0 or 1 is a single-digit number between 2 and 9 *or* any number with more than one digit. Hope this helps:

```
'0*([1-9]\d+|[2-9])'
```

Comment: Well, only if you rely on a strict number format. How about `01` ? The comment by @Wiktor Stribizew has more examples.

Comment: OP says the expression should not allow 0 and 1. My answer is consistent with his specs. But in general, your remark is correct.

Comment: Yes, right. The spec is not saying anything about equivalences. OP talks about numbers though, not texts. So I'm not sure what the OP wants.

Comment: @mkiever I think the edited re handles all weird cases.

Answer (score 0):

That one looks good, first matches the "long" word then the units, with negative backward lookup for minus sign:

```
(?<!-)(\d\d+|[2-9])
```

Python test:

```
z = re.compile(r"(?<!-)(\d\d+|[2-9])")

print(re.findall(z,"-1 1 2 5 -345 134 500"))
```

result:

```
['2', '5', '45', '134', '500']
```

Comment: Try the `([2-9]|\d\d+)` with `-523`. You will get a match. See https://regex101.com/r/XXae5r/1 and http://ideone.com/15vfIG

Comment: tried with python, didn't get a match. That's because I was using `re.match` which matches at start. Edited;

Comment: You probably used `match` not `search`.  Try `200`.  You'll get `2`.

Comment: restarted from scratch. Did not find a problem (yet). I hope noone does :)

Answer (score 0):

A complicated case here:

```
test = ['10', '-10', '001', '000', '33', '-010', '010', '-1 001 02 005 -345 134 500']

[re.findall(r"(?<![0-9-])0*[2-9](?![0-9])|(?<![0-9-])(?:0*[1-9][0-9]{1,})(?![0-9])", t) for t in test]
# [['10'], [], [], [], ['33'], [], ['010'], ['02', '005', '134', '500']]
```

- `(?<![0-9-])0*[2-9](?![0-9])` matches a single digit positive number from 2 to 9;
- `(?<![0-9-])(?:0*[1-9][0-9]{1,})(?![0-9])` matches a multi digit positive number and the not all digits including and above the decade should be zero

This can be simplified to:

```
[re.findall(r"(?<![0-9-])0*(?:[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)(?![0-9])", t) for t in test]

# [['10'], [], [], [], ['33'], [], ['010'], ['02', '005', '134', '500']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, if you wish to match just integers:

```
[1-9]\d+|[2-9]
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/RdKi6R/2)

It contains two parts: the first checks if it is a single digit between 2 and 9. The second part matches any 2+ digit number beginning with 1 or more. This will not match numbers like `01`, `00`, or `5e3`.

Comment: Try any two or more digit number that starts with 2-9.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Oops, fixed

Comment: @DYZ There is an infinite amount of cases this simple regex won't fit: including leading zeroes, decimals, exponential notation, binary, hexadecimal, etc., etc. As long as the OP fails to specify, it's anyone's guess what the format is, but no leading zero's seems as good an assumption as any.

Comment: @brianpck OP says that 01 and 00 should not be accepted. So apparently she does care about leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.isdigit() and not string.startswith("0") and string != "1"
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer].

Answer (score -1):

There is similar answer, but this one should be correct

```
([1-9][0-9]+|[2-9])
```

examle here https://regex101.com/r/BHnvzC/3

Comment: `00` will match this.

Comment: updated answer. But OP should probably specify, if the numbers are in the middle of text, or its each on one line. Its too general to match everything.